# Replace the word that doesnot match the dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, replace

The ask is to create and modify a new column 'ans' in three steps:

- In the column 'ans' - Map the words in the dictionary to column 'text'. TRICKY PART: If there r two words then put the key two times.
- In the column 'ans' - Replace content of column 'text' **not in** the dictionary to 'O'
- In the column 'ans' - Modify the keys that are not preceeded by a 'O' to replace 'B' to 'I' Example 'O O O B-name B-name' to be changed to 'O O O B-name I-name'

Below code example will make it clearer:

```py
#The Code
import pandas as pd
#Creating dictionary
dict_1 = {
        'B-name' : ['Ankit', 'Aishwarya', 'Shaurya', 'Shivangi'],
        'B-acc' : ['bank account', 'Account number', 'bank acc num']
}

#Creating dataframe
data = ['Ankit has a bank account in HSBC.', 'shivangi forgot her bank acc num', 'Aishwarya met shaurya']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['text'])

#The answer should look like:
data = (['Ankit has a bank account in HSBC.', 'B-name O O B-acc I-acc O O'],
        ['shivangi forgot her bank acc num', 'B-name O O B-acc I-acc I-acc'], ['Aishwarya met shaurya','B-name O B-name'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['text','ans'])
df
```

Comment: What challenges do you have? It's not clear on your post

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Creating dictionary
dict_1 = {
        'B-name': ['Ankit', 'Aishwarya', 'Shaurya', 'Shivangi'],
        'B-acc': ['bank account', 'Account number', 'bank acc num']
}

# Creating dataframe
data = ['Ankit has a bank account in HSBC.', 'shivangi forgot her bank acc num', 'Aishwarya met shaurya']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['text'])

# Create a new column named 'ans'
df['ans'] = ""

# Map the words in the dictionary to column 'text' and add them to column 'ans'
for word in df['text']:
    for key, values in dict_1.items():
        if word in values:
            for value in values:
                df.loc[df['text'] == word, 'ans'] += f"{key} {value}"

# Replace content of column 'text' not in the dictionary to 'O'
for i in range(len(df)):
    for key, values in dict_1.items():
        if df.loc[i, 'text'] not in values:
            df.loc[i, 'ans'] += " O"

# Modify the keys that are not preceeded by a 'O' to replace 'B' to 'I'
for i in range(len(df)):
    if not df.loc[i, 'ans'].startswith("O"):
        df.loc[i, 'ans'] = df.loc[i, 'ans'].replace("B-", "I-")

# Print the dataframe
print(df)
```

Comment: The column 'ans' didnot match the expected results. It produced 'O O'. The expected answer looks like the dataframe df in the code provided in the question